# Is it possible to define a common setter method for multiple class properties in python?

Tags: python, optimization, properties, setter

I have a custom class whose instances are initialized with several attributes `foo, bar, ...` that are numeric values or strings. These attributes are used by several class methods to calculate additional attributes of the class instance. I would like to define these attributes as properties, so that when changing them, the additional attributes are recalculated. The following works:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
        self._foo = foo
        self._bar = bar


    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
    @foo.setter
    def foo(self,new_foo):
       old_foo = self._foo:
        self._foo = new_foo
        if old_foo != new_foo:
            self._force_recalc()

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar
    @bar.setter
    def bar(self,new_bar):
        old_bar = self._bar:
        self._bar = new_bar
        if old_bar != new_bar:
            self._force_recalc()

    def _force_recalc(self)
    # call some methods that recalculate attributes
```

However, two aspects strike me as inelegant:

- The setter methods are basically copy-paste with only the variable names adjusted. But I couldn't come up with a solution that makes use of a common setter method.
- Is there a way to avoid `old_foo` and `old_bar`? They result from the fact that `_force_recalc` must be called *after* `foo` and `bar` were reset, but only if their value changed.

Comment: Try overriding `__setattr__` instead

Comment: @rdas: Could you give an example? Maybe as a full answer?

Comment: Don't use `property` write your own descriptor, see [this answer to a different quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63241216/5014455)

Comment: You could define a `@recalc` decorator that you use on all the setters.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried the solution suggested by @Barmar. This works, but lead to the problem of an unnecessary amount of recalculations during initialization of all the properties. Addtionally, they still had to be defined individually and I was unable to check whether the value actually changed.

Following @juanpa.arrivillaga's advice, I defined my own decorator class and ended up with something like this:

```
class MyClass:

    class _MyProperty:
        def __init__(self, value=None):
            self.value = value
        def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
            return self.value
        def __set__(self, instance, value):
            if value != self.value:
                self.value = value
                instance._force_recalc()

    @classmethod
    def _set_init_state(cls,values):
        cls.foo,cls.bar = [cls._MyProperty(value) for value in values]


    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
        self._set_init_state((foo,bar))
        self._force_recalc()


    def _force_recalc(self)
    # call some methods that recalculate attributes
```

While this definitely looks less repetitive, it can probably be argued that the former was more explicit. However, I like it and it solves my original request.